A possible variation of a nim game, where we pick a pile and remove all other.
Recently a friend and I have been discussing a problem we saw somewhere:
Alice and Bob are playing a game where they have n piles of stones. In one move one can pick a particular pile and remove all other. Then they have to split the chosen pile into exactly n piles with at least one stone each. One who doesn't have a move loses.
The constraint were: n <= 1e6, a[i] <= 1e18.
Initially I thought that the setup is very similar to a Sprague-Grundy problem. I can consider calculating the grundy values of a few number, and try finding a pattern relating to n. First of all calculating the grundy values are difficult to find in itself. I have to consider the transition: splitting the number into all possible multisets of size n, xoring the grundy values of the individual elements together and taking the mex amongst all possible multisets. This is in and of itself is a huge task to accomplish. However let's say we do it somehow.
But I don't think these are the correct grundy values for the problem. Picking a pile is not independent of the other piles. Hence xoring is wrong. I have calculated the grundy values for a problem in which I split a pile into n piles. The one who cannot make a valid split loses.
I wonder if this is even solvable by the Sprague-Grundy theorem? Can anyone please help me solve this problem? I welcome people to comment on why or why not my initial setup for solving it by grundy values is correct.

For $n=2$, a first-player win seems to be when either pile has an even number of stones, and a second-player win seems to be when both piles are odd.  Winning play is to take an even pile and split it into two odd numbers.  $n=3$ does not look much more complicated, modulo $6$ rather than $2$. Perhaps you could try other small $n$.

2, 2 is a second player win.

Why? Faced with $2,2$ piles, the first player chooses either pile (they are the same), discarding the other pile,  and splits the chosen pile into $1,1$ piles.  The other player now  cannot "split the chosen pile into exactly $n$ piles with at least one stone each" since neither pile has $2$ stones, and so loses.

correct I got confused
